# Converting XLS to CSV for "New" Files Only

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, xlsx

**I have:**

- .xlsx files being automatically imported on a daily basis to a google
  drive folder

**I want:**

- each file converted to a CSV and saved to a different folder
- each file converted to a Google Sheet and saved to a different folder
- the original xlsx file not deleted
- BUT only for files that have been added since I last ran the script

I pieced the below code together from [this post "Unzip File Only if New in Google Apps Script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644572/unzip-file-only-if-new-in-google-apps-scripts) and from [this post "Converting all files in drive folder from sheets to CSV and add to new folder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210740/converting-all-files-in-drive-folder-from-sheets-to-csv-and-add-to-new-folder). However I have an issue -- when I try to run this I am getting an error message

**GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.copy failed with error: File not found: [Name of SheetsFolder]**

Can anyone tell what the error is by looking at this code?

```
function makeCSV() {
  //Add folder ID to select the folder where excel files are placed
  var SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("12XqAVzwzgl4a7Z1s6zn5VRcHiZ1vQdsT")
  //Add folder ID to save the where csv files to be placed
  var DestinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Z_mUXs3FFDTN7XLk8EN9D5QOxVD8lZfB")
  //Add folder ID to save where the google sheets to be placed
  var SheetsFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("17k_bl7Of2jH3U_TjaiiY_8BBOds4uSbT")

  //Select the XLS and XLSX files from source folder using the Mimetype of Microsoft Excel
  var searchQuery = "mimeType='" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL + "' or mimeType='" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY + "'";
  var sourceFiles = SourceFolder.searchFiles(searchQuery);

  var now = new Date(); //get current time after you fetch the file list from Drive.

  //Get script properties and check for stored "last_execution_time"
  var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var cutoff_datetime = properties.getProperty('last_execution_time');

  //if we have last execution date, stored as a string, convert it to a Date object.
  if(cutoff_datetime)
     cutoff_datetime = new Date(cutoff_datetime);

  //Loop over all the XLS files
  while (sourceFiles.hasNext()){
    var sourceFile = sourceFiles.next();

    //if no stored last execution, or file is newer than last execution, process the file.
    if(!cutoff_datetime || file.getDateCreated() > cutoff_datetime){
      var fileId = sourceFile.getId();

      //Copy the XLS file to the Sheets Folder as a google sheet 
      var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.copy({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{id: SheetsFolder}]}, fileId);

      //Get the data from the google sheet using the SpreadsheetApp
      var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.id).getSheets();sheets[0].getDataRange().getValues()

      //Create a csv file using the data from the google sheet     
      var csv = sheets.map(function(sheet) {return sheet.getDataRange().getValues().reduce(function(csv, row) {return csv += row.join(",") + "\n"}, "")}); DestinationFolder.createFile(spreadsheet.title + ".csv", csv, MimeType.CSV)
    }
  }

  //store "now" as last execution time as a string, to be referenced on next run.
  properties.setProperty('last_execution_time',now.toString());
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

EDIT 1: Thank you to Tanaike for helping to troubleshoot! The above code had two issues: one was the issue Tanaike points out in his comment. The second is that "file" should read "sourceFile" in the if statement. I am posting the correct code below for posterity.

```
function makeCSV() {
  //Add folder ID to select the folder where excel files are placed
  var SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("12XqAVzwzgl4a7Z1s6zn5VRcHiZ1vQdsT")
  //Add folder ID to save the where csv files to be placed
  var DestinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Z_mUXs3FFDTN7XLk8EN9D5QOxVD8lZfB")
  //Add folder ID to save where the google sheets to be placed
  var SheetsFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("17k_bl7Of2jH3U_TjaiiY_8BBOds4uSbT")

  //Select the XLS and XLSX files from source folder using the Mimetype of Microsoft Excel
  var searchQuery = "mimeType='" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL + "' or mimeType='" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY + "'";
  var sourceFiles = SourceFolder.searchFiles(searchQuery);

  var now = new Date(); //get current time after you fetch the file list from Drive.

  //Get script properties and check for stored "last_execution_time"
  var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var cutoff_datetime = properties.getProperty('last_execution_time');

  //if we have last execution date, stored as a string, convert it to a Date object.
  if(cutoff_datetime)
     cutoff_datetime = new Date(cutoff_datetime);

  //Loop over all the XLS files
  while (sourceFiles.hasNext()){
    var sourceFile = sourceFiles.next();

    //if no stored last execution, or file is newer than last execution, process the file.
    if(!cutoff_datetime || sourceFile.getDateCreated() > cutoff_datetime){
      var fileId = sourceFile.getId();

      //Copy the XLS file to the Sheets Folder as a google sheet 
      var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.copy({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{id:"17k_bl7Of2jH3U_TjaiiY_8BBOds4uSbT"}]}, fileId);

      //Get the data from the google sheet using the SpreadsheetApp
      var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.id).getSheets();sheets[0].getDataRange().getValues()

      //Create a csv file using the data from the google sheet     
      var csv = sheets.map(function(sheet) {return sheet.getDataRange().getValues().reduce(function(csv, row) {return csv += row.join(",") + "\n"}, "")}); DestinationFolder.createFile(spreadsheet.title + ".csv", csv, MimeType.CSV)
    }
  }

  //store "now" as last execution time as a string, to be referenced on next run.
  properties.setProperty('last_execution_time',now.toString());
}
```

Comment: How about modifying from `parents: [{id: SheetsFolder}]}` to `parents: [{id: "17k_bl7Of2jH3U_TjaiiY_8BBOds4uSbT"}]}`? Because it is required to use the folder ID to `Drive.Files.copy` instead of the folder object. But I'm not sure whether your issue is only this. So I proposed this as a commented.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike! The code had two isses. 1.) the issue you mention and 2.) in the if statement should read "sourceFile.getDateCreated()". It works now!